# Is there a better way to access deeply nested controls?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, code-behind

I've started work at a company and don't have full access to their previously built objects/frameworks/etc and I've been tasked with creating a new system, using their libraries / objects / etc.  I can override most of their libraries, but without seeing what exactly is going on I'm finding it challenging to work with.

It is all in .net webforms, which I'm really not all that familiar with as well.

They have a customs Model-View-Controller sort of system built on top of webforms, which generates full control ascx pages, however of course the ascx file is simply one line, the code behind is empty, so all I can really see is the markup dynamically generated.

I will have markup written like:

```
<div id="id1">
  <div id="id2">
    <div id="id3">
      <table id="tt_id1">
        <input id="myModelNameID">
```

etc, etc.

The objects as well are named differently in .net vs what's generated in the markup, so this makes things even more challenging - I have to always examine the objects for a while to find the full path of where my control is located.

What is the easiest way to access a deeply nested control?

I've tried to use references to different ID's (like ClientID vs ID), etc.  I have found examples here and there but usually people are doing something like what I'm doing.

I'm trying to avoid writing 30 findControls  , etc.  I could write a method I suppose that would do this, but I'm hoping there's an easier way even or something already available.

When I am trying to access anything in code-behind to access objects I am examining them in the debugger or using a dumper class or reflection, and then writing something like this:

```
    //This is an example that would add a button in a table.

    Button MyButt = new Button();
    MyButt.Text = "Click Me";

    //Split into sections for readability...

    Control c = Page.FindControl("ctl00").FindControl("Form1");
    Control c2 = c.FindControl("MainPage").FindControl("id1");
    Control MyTable = c2.FindControl("id2").FindControl("myTable1");
    MyTable.Controls.Add(MyButt);
```

Comment: Oh god, that sounds absolutely terrible. You have my condolences. I don't know about finding super nested code, but maybe have a look at the free [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) decompiler to see if you can reverse-engineer the project?

Comment: "Model-Value-Controller" Do you mean Model View Controller?

Comment: You might be missing something about the original architecture.  What is driving the dynamic controls?  Is there some sort of markup-language or database?  I would look a little closer.

Comment: A variation on https://odetocode.com/articles/71.aspx

Comment: @Bedir - Yes.  Typo :)

Comment: @matt-dot-net - The dynamic controls are defined in the "model" part.  ie "string Full_Name {get;set;} " would render a textbox with ID Full_Name and a "Full Name" label.  There is no database component.  What they created, at the time, was great and at the time ahead of it's time.  This is a 15 year old site as I write this.  Having said that if you want to edit anything out of the norm it's a bit of a pain.  Other developers here just write their own markup - I've been trying to use their "engine" as it's a time saver but I'll probably have to write large markup pages in the end :(